# Get URL and Change Javascript Variable on Request for Rails Partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have multiple posts on a page that possess comments, and have written most of the implementation for asynchronous load of the comments for a post upon clicking a button at the bottom of a post.

Currently I have ruby for each post like:

```
<div id="<%= 'post' + post_pieces[-1].to_s %>"></div>
```

That ends up rendering like `<div id="post1"></div> , <div id="post2"></div> , <div id="post3"></div>` etc. in each post.

The problem I have is that the js file that loads the content on each request:

```
$("#post_comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @comments) %>");
```

I am unsure how to get the request URL in javascript and change the content #post_comments to match the 'post1', 'post2', etc. on request.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I can something almost working using js: 'post' + window.location.pathname.substr(-2,2) which if the id is two digits long would give me the appropriate id, but I'm still not sure how to have it change on request.

Comment: The issue is that its returning the current url, not the request.

Comment: I still don't know how to do this natively with javascript, but embedding ruby into the code works: $(<%= 'post' + request.original_url[-2..-1] %>).html("<%= escape_javascript(render @comments) %>"); Now I just need to figure out how to make it work on all post.id lengths, not just 2 digit

Comment: this works: $(<%= 'post' + request.path.scan(/\d/).join('') %>).html("<%= escape_javascript(render @comments) %>");